# perl: useing commas in hash values

Tags: string, perl, hash

I have key value pairs as "statement:test,data" where 'test,data' is the value for hash. While trying to create a hash with such values, perl splits the values on the comma. Is there a way around this where strings with commas can be used as values

Comment: I doubt that it splits the value. Please show some code. `%x = ( statement => 'test,data')` should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl won't split a string on a comma unless you tell it to.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.16;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump 'ddx';

my $data = "statement:test,data";
my %hash;

my ($key, $value) = split(":", $data);

$hash{$key} = $value;

ddx \%hash;
```

gives:

```
# split.pl:14: { statement => "test,data" }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in Perl that stops you from using 'test,data' as hash value.
If your incoming string is literally "statement:test,data", you can use this code to add into hash:

```
my ($key, $value) = ($string =~ /(\w+):(.*)/);
next unless $key and $value;  # skip bad stuff - up to you
$hash{$key} = $value;
```